# perl determine URL SSL certificate key length

Tags: perl, ssl, key

I'm trying to figure a way to fetch the certificate issuer and key length for a long list of URL.

Any Perl module could provide that?

Best regards,

Yannick Bergeron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are several keys involved in TLS

- the public key in the certificate
- the key used for symmetric encryption inside the TLS connection

The following code should give you both, the bits of the public key and the cipher used for symmetric encryption. The cipher is given as a string of the algorithm used, the effective key length depends on the algorithm. With public key it is similar, e.g. you might compare the key length as long as the same algorithm is used, but when comparing RSA and elliptic curves the key length cannot be simply compared.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use IO::Socket::SSL;

my $cl = IO::Socket::SSL->new('www.google.com:443') or die $!;
my $cipher = $cl->get_cipher;
my $issuer = $cl->peer_certificate('issuer');
my $pkey = Net::SSLeay::X509_get_pubkey($cl->peer_certificate);
my $bits = Net::SSLeay::EVP_PKEY_bits($pkey);
my $pkey_type = Net::SSLeay::OBJ_nid2sn( Net::SSLeay::EVP_PKEY_id($pkey));

print "cipher: $cipher\n";
print "cert: issuer=$issuer pkey=$pkey_type/$bits\n";
```

For me this code returns:

```
cipher: ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA
cert: issuer=/C=US/O=Google Inc/CN=Google Internet Authority G2 pkey=rsaEncryption/2048
```

If you need to check lots of web sites in a short time you might speed the code up by using non-blocking TCP connects and later non-blocking SSL handshakes and thus handling multiple targets in parallel. Please refer to the documentation of IO::Socket::INET and IO::Socket::SSL in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `VERIFY_PEER` callback in [Net::SSLeay](http://search.cpan.org/~mikem/Net-SSLeay-1.58/lib/Net/SSLeay.pod).

```
use Net::SSLeay;
use Data::Dumper;
use strict;

# install the VERIFY callback
Net::SSLeay::set_verify ($ssl, Net::SSLeay::VERIFY_PEER, sub {
   # get out what you want here 
   # (this is just an example to allow you to see what's available)
   print Dumper(\@_);
});

# make an HTTPS request
my ($page) = get_https('www.example.com', 443, '/');
```

See what that gives you. Net::SSLeay also implements a bunch of type-specific certificate APIs from OpenSSL, so there's lots you can look at.

Change the `Dumper` line to whatever you want to pull out. Do something like

```
my @domains;
Net::SSLeay::set_verify ($ssl, Net::SSLeay::VERIFY_PEER, sub {
   push @domains, { 
     somekey      => $_[0]->{somekey},
     someotherkey => $_[0]->{someotherkey}
   }
});
```

In any case, just put the calls to `get_https` in into function and call it for each element in the array of domains to be checked.

You might wish to use [Parallel::ForkManager](http://search.cpan.org/~szabgab/Parallel-ForkManager-1.06/lib/Parallel/ForkManager.pm) to fork off multiple processes to verify your list items concurrently.